# Resize picture without losing quality

Tags: php, image-resizing

I have to resize images with PHP.
But... the quality is very, very bad !! (look at the picture)

Here my code :

```
function _copyAndResizeImage($id, $wanted_width, $isAdvert=true) {
// The file
if ($isAdvert) {
    $filename = "../upload/images/advert/".$id."/1.jpg";
} else {
    $filename = "../upload/images/user/".$id.".jpg";
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

if ($width == 0) {
    $percent=1;
} else {
    $percent = $wanted_width / $width;
}

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
if ($isAdvert) {
    imagejpeg($image_p, '../upload/images/advert/'.$id.'/1-'.$wanted_width.'.jpg');
} else {
    imagejpeg($image_p, '../upload/images/user/'.$id.'-'.$wanted_width.'.jpg');
}

}
```

[image]

Have you got an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Well, that's what enlarging a small image is going to do, no way around that. How large is your original picture?

Comment: I've don't got the source but, the size of source if normally bigger

Comment: try some libraries like [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/), or add the image quality parameter in function `imagejpeg`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're resizing smaller raster-based (pixel) images, you will lose quality upon resizing it to a larger size. This is expected. If you don't want this to happen, use SVG's.

Answer (score 0):

imagejpeg jas a third optional parameter ranging from 0 to 100 for quality:

bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )

Defaults to 75 should be pretty ok normally.

Comment: Even 75% image quality - you wouldn't notice a loss like what he's seeing; the difference between 75 and 100 is nominal for low resolution images.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this myself. I decided to output the resized jpeg as a png and it worked wonders!

```
imagepng(...);
```